# Differences between interface entity and gate term in NED in Omnet++?

Tags: omnet++

What differences are there between interface entity and gate in Omnet++? I don't understand actually differences.

In INET simulations, network interface modules are the primary means of communication between network nodes. They represent the required combination of software and hardware elements from an operating system point-of-view.

Network interfaces are implemented with OMNeT++ compound modules that conform to the INetworkInterface module interface. Network interfaces can be further categorized as wired and wireless; they conform to the IWiredInterface and IWirelessInterface NED types, respectively, which are subtypes of INetworkInterface.

Answer (score 1):

A *gate* is a term in the core OMNeT++ simulator describing the C++ objects that are used to connect *modules*.

A *network interface* is a term in the INET Framework (and in real world) that is used to connect network *nodes*. i.e. This is a higher level concept than gates.